# Does a French passport holder require a US visa for business trips?

Tags: visas, usa

I am a French citizen and I am going to USA to work with a company during a Toy Fair event. The job is not contractual and not paid directly. The company covers my travel and accommodation costs. I will stay in the USA for about a week.

Do I need a visa for such a travel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you don't need a visa to visit the US.

A French citizen can visit for 90 days for business or leisure without obtaining a visa. What you need is a travel authorization ("ESTA"), that you can apply for online.

You can apply at the [USCBP ESTA website](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/). There is a $14 fee.

Comment: Indeed, a good article in french about the ETSA program can be found [here](http://french.france.usembassy.gov/esta.html)

Comment: you're wrong. He specifically mentioned a BUSINESS trip, those do not fall under the Visa waiver program.

Comment: You're wrong. From the ESTA page: "You plan to travel to the United States for business or pleasure."

Comment: you need ESTA clearance for both business AND pleasure, in addition to any visa you may also need.

Comment: @jwenting that is not correct. An ESTA is NOT required if you hold a visa. An ESTA is required only if you using the Visa Waiver program (which only covers certain things - it does cover some categories of business travel, but not typically not 'work').

Answer (score -4):

Yes, for business travel (which this is) you're going to need a business visa (NOT a tourist visa).
You may or may not also need a work permit (especially if the company is a US company, unlikely if it's a French company and all you're doing is representing them to potential US customers). The US embassy or consulate nearest you should be able to give you a definite answer.

Comment: This contradicts the other answer and what ESTA's site seems to say...

Comment: in that case things have changed. My father travelled to the US extensively on business and always (even for a visit of occasionally only a few hours) would need a business visa. In the end the embassy just handed him an unlimited business visa, so he didn't have to go to them every other week for a fresh one.